# pop up and grid view on one button

Tags: html, button, gridview

I try to call gridview and pop up on one button click

pop up

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#divcontainer").dialog({
          modal: true,
          autoOpen: false,
          title: "Chart",
          width: 600,
          height: 450
      });
      $("#search_data").click(function () {
          $("#divcontainer").dialog('open');
      });
  });
```

button

```
<input type="button" ID="search_data"    runat="server" class="sear_btn"  value="Search Data" OnServerClick="search_data_Click" />
```

now when i remove this `OnServerClick="search_data_Click"`  from button then pop up display and grid view not display and when i add this then pop up not appear grid view display

whereas i want both on one button 
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger your `search_data_Click` Function after Dialog show code in script.

```
$("#search_data").click(function () {
 $("#divcontainer").dialog('open'); 
 search_data_Click();});
```

Comment: i try this but gridview not display

Comment: Can You show me your code demo. Becoz I have use this type of code lot of time so dam sure its working.

Comment: Alert and popup are open at same time .

Comment: there is only pop up in your js fiddle

Comment: I Got your issue @SUPER_USER Please check it again https://jsfiddle.net/psbtmhup/16/

Comment: no .. i want to display gridview on page and pop up must open like pop up

Comment: Also check it..............................................  $("#search_data").click(function () { search_data_Click(); $("#divcontainer").dialog('open');  });

Comment: One more thing .. Add this  $("#divcontainer").dialog('open');  at the end in  search_data_Click() function.

Comment: i try this..  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("#divcontainer").dialog({
              modal: true,
              autoOpen: false,
              title: "Chart",
              width: 600,
              height: 450
          });
          $("#search_data").click(function () {
              $("#divcontainer").dialog('open');
              search_data_Click();
          });
      });

      
</script>